# Putty- Incoming packet was garbled on decryption

Tags: virtualbox, putty

I am using putty (v 0.60) to connect virtualbox(v 4.2.16) CentOS. But i am getting the error "Incoming packet was garbled on decryption".

When i connect to virtual box IP by SSH its asking me to enter the credentials. After entering the credentails i am getting the above error. It prevents the normal operation.

I have tried using 0.62, 0.63 and changed "Connection->SSH and move "Blowfish" to the top of the list under "Encryption cipher selection policy". Still i am not able to achieve it. But when i install AVG anti-virus i am able to reach my virtualbox centOS. I cant use this anti-virus in my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this was fixed as the question is a bit old, but in my situation the cause was using `plink` in the proxy-settings of Putty. After I turned on the logging (the radio-buttons just below the proxy-command) `plink` had some plain text output about a non-cached server I wanted to use as a proxy.

As it also printed the full command line for `plink`, I basically copied and executed that in a command shell. I accepted the new server and the error went away in Putty.